# Bounded Convergence $\lambda$-a.e.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

As the title says. So let $\{f_n\}_n$ be a sequence of Lebesgue measurable functions that converge $\lambda-$a.e. to a real valued function $f$ and let $E$ be Lebesgue measurable such that $\lambda(E)< \infty$ where $\lambda$ denotes Lebesgue measure. Suppose that there is an $M>0$ such that $|f_n(x)| \leq M 
\hspace{2mm}\forall x \in E$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Show that $f$ is Lebesgue integrable on $E$ and use the dominated convergence theorem to prove that $$\int_E fd\lambda = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_E f_n d\lambda$$

Heres my attempt: Since we have that $\{f_n\}_n$ is a sequence of Lebesgue measurable functions that converge $\lambda-$a.e. to $f$, there is Lebesgue measurable set $F$ such that $\lambda(F)=0$ and that $f_n(x) \rightarrow f(x)$ for $x \in F^c$. Since $M>0$ we can set $g(x) = M$ for all $x\in E$, and so for all $n$ we have $|f_n(x)|\leq g$. So now we can apply the DCT to show that $f$ is Lebesgue integrable and that the integral equation holds, but my only concern is that $f_n(x)\rightarrow f(x)$ on $F^c$. What do I do to relate $F^c$ and $E$ because that seems to be the hiccup here.

Comment: $\int_E = \int_{E\cap F^c}.$

Comment: Why is this the case, and does this only apply to that last step? I've seen this once before and I think this is my confusion, why is that okay to do/how does it work?  @spaceisdarkgreen

Comment: I mean that completely generally for any measurable function $h$, we have $ \int_E h d\lambda = \int_{E\setminus F}h d\lambda,$ since $\lambda(F) = 0$. Perhaps it would be more familar if I say it is because $h1_E = h1_{E\setminus F}$ almost everywhere? (Or do you need help with the fact that functions equal almost everywhere have the same integral?)

Comment: Gotcha that explains my confusion there thank you. Now one last thing, since $f_n \rightarrow f$ for  $x \in F^c$, then $f_n \rightarrow f$ for $x \in$ $E \setminus F^c$ as well and then I'd be done right? Its just that satisfying the conditions of the DCT require that $f_n \rightarrow f$ for $x \in E$, and as of now I don't specifically have that. Thank you in advance for the help on this! @spaceisdarkgreen

Comment: Yeah, (assuming you mean $E\cap F^c$  or equiv $E\setminus F$ instead of $E\setminus F^c$). The idea is to forget about $E$ and work with $E\setminus F$ instead... then the DCT will say you need $f_n\to f$ for $x\in E\setminus F$ and you do have that.

Comment: Yes that is what I was going for, thank you!